# Should this be a wiki question?

Tags: discussion

I am having second thoughts about one of the recent questions:

[In what order does it make sense to upgrade suspension components?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/in-what-order-does-it-make-sense-to-upgrade-suspension-components)

I originally answered it (at length) but, now that I re-read it and the associated commentary, it's not clear that this is an answerable question.  On some of the other sites, as soon as the question comes close to being a discussion rather than yes/no answerable, it gets tagged a wiki.

In this specific case, should we make it a wiki?  If so / not, what does this question tell us about our theme and intent for questions in general.

NOTE: I could just wiki-ify it myself but I'd rather present the question for discussion before pulling that trigger.

Comment: I think, as of now, the question should remain as is.  But if the activity on it were to shoot up and people are staring new discussions on it, then I'd wiki-fy it.

Comment: I'd wait until the activity starts to get out of hand, especially comments.

Comment: Okay, then the follow-up question is then: where is the line for a wiki question on our site?  I think either the FAQ needs additional clarity or meta could use a discussion of the topic.  Feel free to propose in the answers here.

Comment: It seems that some people don't want questions to be turned into a community wiki because they quit losing rep on it once it occurs.  I'm interested in seeing some answer on this.  I don't really feel like I can put a stake in the ground on either side of this as I think I lack any real clarity on the issue.